# how to convert byte array ( or ArrayList<Byte ) to bit array ?

Tags: android

I need to convert on android byte array ( or ArrayList ) to bit array.
I still new on android world ... and i can't find any why to do it ?

any help please 
thanks.

Comment: You mean convert each byte in the array to array of 0s and 1s?

Comment: What is a "bit array", in Java terms?

Comment: because i nedd convert byte array to bits

Comment: A byte is 8 bits.  Do you need to know how to tell if a given bit is a 1 or a 0?  Or something else?  There is no such thing a a bit array, a byte is the smallest variable in Java.

Comment: i need to convet ArrayList<Byte> to BitSet